# Watch App to Determine if User Logged in on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an existing iOS app that uses Parse.com.  You can login with username and password, Facebook, or twitter, as well as create a new login.  I am getting an update ready that has a WatchKit Extension to run a slimmed down version on the new Apple Watch.  What I am wondering how to do is have the watch check if there is an existing `PFUser` on the iPhone, or if even the iPhone user is logged out.  What would you suggest for this?

I have the application ID for the Parse app in my AppDelegate, and initialize `PFTwitterUtils` and `PFFacebookUtils` in the AppDelegate, but those do not get called when running from watch.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where Parse stores their data, but I don't think it is in your shared app group folder.  If that is the case then parse in your extension would not have access to the same data as parse running in your iOS app (though I am not 100% positive on that.)  I would recommend putting a "LoggedIn" setting in your shared user defaults.  You can update that setting every time the user logs in or out in your iOS app and then just check that setting in your watch app.

Comment: I'm just trying to think of ways to handle this if the only time an Apple Watch user has experienced the app is on their wrist, and not the iPhone...a way to handle all aspects without ever requiring the iPhone app itself to be launched, but still communicate with it, if it has.

Comment: You can still use the setting in your shared user defaults.  If the iOS app never runs, then the setting will not be set to true.  Then when you check it in the WatchKit extension it will show that the user is not logged in.

Comment: Any recommendation on allowing for new user signup from watch? Would of course allow login with Facebook and Twitter as a way to create new user, but the other Contains 4 fields including name, email, and user name choice.  Could be difficult to dictate some of those....

Comment: If the user is not logged in I would recommend that you tell them to open the iPhone app and have them log in there.  It will be easier for a user to log in on their phone than on the watch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago, I finally decided to use darwinNotifications to send notifications between iPhone app and applewatch,and to share data between them I used SharedGroups.
So when the user login:
1) I write the user in the shared groups
2) I send a darwin notification from the iOS app to the apple watch
3) Apple watch receive the darwin notification and reads the shared groups to check if there is a new user.

This code sends a darwin notification:

```
//Write the user on shared groups 
CFNotificationCenterRef notification = CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter ();
CFStringRef UserLoggedInCFString = (__bridgeCFStringRef)DarwinNotificationUserLoggedIn;
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(notification, UserLoggedInCFString, NULL, NULL, YES);
```

This code on the applewatch detect the notification:

```
CFNotificationCenterRef notificationUserLoggedIn = CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter (); // 1
CFStringRef userLoggedInCFString = (__bridgeCFStringRef)DarwinNotificationUserLoggedIn;
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(notificationUserLoggedIn, (__bridge const void *)(self), &userHasLogguedIn, userLoggedInCFString,NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

void userHasLogguedIn(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                            void *observer,
                            CFStringRef name,
                            const void *object,
                            CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    //Read the user from shared groups.
}
```

Comment: Just an opinion question: do you allow them to login any using the watch, or make it to where logging in must be done on the iPhone side first?  Trying to predict how most of the apps will work so I can have mine not be completely different at launch.

Comment: FYI, MMWormhole is a nicer API for communicating with your extension. https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Comment: In my case, the login is done in the iPhone app, and the watch receives a notification of that login. (but you can login the user in the applewatch if you want, just that I haven't done that functionality).

Comment: I just want to make sure that whatever the state is on one device, it stays the same on the other.

Comment: @StephenJohnson It seems in the documentation for MMWormhole that it only works if the container app is running in the background.  So, wouldn't really work for my scenario.